# Integrating Camera Class and Sensor Class

Tags: android, nested, android-camera, accelerometer

I have two classes. Class 1 is extending Fragment and Class 2 is extending AppCompatActivity. 
Class1 is providing custom camera preview and class 2 is reading Accelerometer data and calculate Angle of inclination on click of a button. My intention is to combines both these classes and provide a single activity with Camera Preview on top and Button & TextView at the bottom. Can anyone tell me how to implement this idea ?

> 1. Whether to have these classes separate and send the calculatedAngle String through Bundles to and fro by calling startActivty()?
> 2. Or Combine these two classes by using Nested Classes concept ?

Basically Camera preview needs to be continuously displayed while the Button click should display angle at bottom at any time. Please let me know, I tried many options and confused right now. Let me know if the code block is needed.